# A class whose internal representation is not exposed to the user and can change transparently, what is this example?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation

In *C++*, a class whose internal representation is not exposed to the user and can change transparently.

This is an example of derivation, abstraction, polymorphism, encapsulation, inheritance ?

I think it is encapsulation.

A member data is private, it is not exposed to users, but it can be changed by member functions.

Correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I suspect that the author of the homework question had "abstraction" in mind, but it's ambiguously phrased.

Comment: Abstraction and Polymorphism were the first things that came to my mind, assuming "internal representation is not exposed to the user" means that the private data and private methods are not even declared in the class in question so the user can't see them at all. But if they are declared, just not accessible to the user's code, then Encapsulation would make more sense.

Comment: To me that is textbook encapsulation.

Comment: There's more than one way to skin that cat.  A common technique is to expose only a pure abstract class (an interface) and a factory function that creates an instance of a hidden derived class that implements the interface.  That's not encapsulation, that's everything else :)

Answer (score 1):

The first (homework) question seems to be an example both of encapsulation and of abstraction.  Who knows what your teacher expects?

As for this:

> A member data is private, it is not exposed to users, but it can be changed by member functions.

If this is a true/false question, and you copied it down verbatim, then the answer is false.  Data members of classes can be public.  If there should be an "if" at the beginning of the sentence, then the answer changes to true.

If you are going to post homework questions there is really no excuse for introducing ambiguity and grammatical mistakes in the transcription phase.

Answer (score 0):

The expected answer is clearly 'encapsulation'.

> This is an example of derivation, abstraction, polymorphism, encapsulation, inheritance ?

Derivation and inheritance are easily ruled out; they might be used to structure the code so it's easy to change the internal representation of the class, but there's nothing in the question that requires them.

'Abstraction' here doesn't refer to abstract classes, but more generally to [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)), which is much broader than hiding internal details to enable implementation code to vary transparently.

Polymorphism is also not the correct answer, however the relationship between polymorphism and encapsulation might confuse some into choosing it.

Encapsulation is the division of code into 'internal' details and 'external' code with the two separated by an interface. Polymorphism is a particular mechanism for choosing or setting what implementation is operative when an interface is accessed through a particular variable. So obviously polymorphism depends on encapsulation to divide 'external' code accessing the polymorphic variable from the implementations, but encapsulation does not have to be used in a polymorphic context.

So with the definition of encapsulation restated here and its relation to polymorphism clarified, it's clear that the question is uniquely identifying encapsulation among these terms.

> A member data is private, it is not exposed to users, but it can be changed by member functions.
>
> Correct ?

If you're referring to member functions' permission to access data members and modify their values that's not what's meant in the question by the "internal representation [...] can change transparently".

What they mean is that the source code corresponding to the hidden, internal details can be rewritten without requiring rewriting any source code corresponding to external code. For example if you have designed a 2d vector that encapsulates its data then you can freely rewrite its implementation (both member data and member functions) to switch between using cartesian coordinates and using a rho-theta representation; the 'external' code will not need to change at all.